# How to add aspect ratio constraint with FluentLayout

Tags: xamarin.ios, cirrious.fluentlayout

Using [Cirrious.FluentLayout](https://github.com/FluentLayout/Cirrious.FluentLayout) how can I add an aspect ratio constraint?

Comment: There are several examples of using a `multiplier` to get a ratio effect https://github.com/FluentLayout/Cirrious.FluentLayout/search?q=multiplier&unscoped_q=multiplier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an extension method that does the trick.

```
public static FluentLayout WithAspectRatio(this UIView view, nfloat ratio) =>
            view.Height().EqualTo().WidthOf(view).WithMultiplier(ratio);
```

Now it's as simple as doing this to get a 1:1 ratio.

```
View.AddConstraints(
                    ...
                    whiteBackground.WithAspectRatio(1f)
                    ...);
```